# PHP Function Global vs. Require

Tags: php, function, global, require

I have a script that runs based on variables in another script. At the top of the script, I require the variables script.

I am trying to make my script easier to edit so I decided to create functions because a lot of my scripts do the exact same thing. In the functions, I need to pull some of the variables set in the variable script. I tried using require and it tends to make the script very slow. I know I can set PHP globals but I read somewhere that using globals is a bad idea? Is this true?

Is there a better way to do this besides using a require in the function or using globals?

Code:

```
function test() 
{
    require('var.php');

    // function code
}
```

OR

```
require('var.php');

function test() 
{
    global $var_variable1, $var_variable2;

    // function code
}
```

Comment: If you do not show the code for you problem , there is no way to suggest anything

Comment: Both ideas are bad, show more code so we can get to the real problem.

Comment: The code is over 1000 lines long. The problem is that require in a function is a bad idea and globals are also a bad idea. Is there any other option besides these? I am trying to pull variables from another script into a function?

Comment: @evanvee , well .. looks like you should already be reading http://php.net/oop5

Answer (score 2):

There is actually third option:

in file *param.php*

```
<?php
    $param = 1234;
?>
```

in file *test.php*

```
<?php

    require 'param.php';

    function foo( $bar )
    {
        var_dump( $bar );
    }

    foo( $param );

?>
```

But you should understand , that this is a very primitive way of dealing with variables and passing instructions from one piece of code to another.

When you are done with learning the basics of PHP language, you should start investigating Object Oriented programming methodology. That would be the way to grow.

Answer (score 1):

When variables are fixed, it's a good solution to use constants.

Create a PHP file with all your constants:

```
<?php
define("FOO",     "something");
define("FOO2",    "someotherthing");
?>
```

By convention use UPPERCASE constant names.
Into your script files use require_once() as the first line to include your script file where you define all your constants.

Do the same with a script containing all your support functions and require_once the file from your scripts.

If possible use OOP with PHP. With objects you can do very cool things.

Comment: Will these then work in the functions  or do I need to require the file still?

Comment: If you require_once() your script where you define all your constants they will be visible globally.